# jQuery/AJAX - Load and unload content into a div when button clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using this code to include a file (thanks M1K1O):

**jQuery Code:**

```
    <script language="javascript">
$(function(){
  $(".classloader").click(function(){
    $("#contenthere").load("/includes/about-info.html");
  });
});
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<p class="classloader">Click Here</p>
<div id="contenthere"></div>
```

But I have problems with character encoding. The included file is saved as iso-8859-2, the main html file is too but still I get "bushes".

How can I solve the problem?

And second question: after a click on 'Click here' text from a file is included. I would like the second click to erase the loaded content. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Karolina

Comment: I solved first problem, I think. Looks like included file should be coded as UTF-8 although main file (where I make an inclusion) is coded as iso-8859-2. Strange.

Second question is still active. Does anyone know the solution? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt your event listener to "toggle" on clicking by checking to see if the `#contenthere` div is populated with your html:

```
<script language="javascript">
 $(function(){
  $(".classloader").click(function(){
    if($('#contenthere').html() == ""){
      $("#contenthere").load("/includes/about-info.html");
    } else {
      $('#contenthere').html("");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

simply `$('#elementId').html("");` is used for `clear` the elements of the selector

Then,

For `empty/clear` the `input` use `$('#elementId').val("");`

Comment: Thanks! This is it.